# Getting into the same data page after a deletion of a row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table where it shows number of rows of specific dates. I want after deletion of a row, to get back to the same page and show the same rows of the same date. Example: if I had 2 rows for the date 06/06/2015 and I deleted one of them I want to get back to the same page and see the other row. I have these codes:

Delete.php:

```
<?php 
require_once ('../include/global.php');
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM appoint WHERE id=".$id;
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($con));
if($result){
    $sql2 = "SELECT date FROM appoint WHERE id=".$id;
    $result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2) or die('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($con)); 
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $result2);
    header("location:appoint.php");


}
else { 
header("location:../update/update_false.php");
}
?>
```

getdata.php:

```
<?php
require_once ('../include/global.php');
    if($_POST['seldate']) {
        $selDate = $_POST['seldate'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE date='$selDate'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
<tr>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['time'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['name'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['date'] ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><form action='/clinic form/appoint/delete.php'=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>' method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Done">
    </form>

    </td>
    </tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

And the page of data display table appoint.php:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Date").change(function(){
            var seldate =$(this).val();
            $("#scheduleDate").html(seldate);
            var dataString = 'seldate='+ seldate;
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getdata.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#Schedule").html(data);
                } 
            });
        });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container12">
    <header>
        <div align="center">
            <div class="column12"> <a href="homepage.php"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a> </div>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <div align="center"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <h1 id="home">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div class="alert"></div>
    <div class="column12" align="left"><B><center>Appointments</B></center><br />
    </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container12" align="center">
    <form action="addApp.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    <table width="700px" class="imagetable" align="center">
    <th align="center">Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Contact Number</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" class="large-fld-app" placeholder="name"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="date" class="large-fld-app" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" name="time" class="large-fld-app"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" class="large-fld-app"/></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="" name="submit" class="imgClass_save" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
//$sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint";
//$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
//$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
?>
<div class="container">
<table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
            Schedule
                <th scope="row">
                    <select name="Date" required class="form-control" id="Date">
                    <option value="">Please Select Date</option>
                    <?php $sql2="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint GROUP BY date";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die($sql2."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
                    while($rows2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $rows2['date'] ?>"><?php echo $rows2['date'] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <td class="schedule-offset" colspan="2" id="scheduleDate"></td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="Schedule"></tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick solution: Put your ajax part into a function.

Change your PHP Code for delete:

```
require_once ('../include/global.php');
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

# Find the date for which you are deleting...
$query = "SELECT date FROM appoint WHERE id = " . $id;
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, $query));
$request_date = $row['date'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM appoint WHERE id=".$id;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($con));
if($result){
    header("Location: appoint.php?date=" . $request_date);
}
else { 
    header("Location: ../update/update_false.php");
}
```

Now when you come back from delete you have a `$_GET['date']`. But when you first load the page you don't have that.

Now change your JS to suit it. Put the AJAX part in a function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Date").change(function(){
        var seldate =$(this).val();
        display_data(seldate);
    });

    // This is the function...
    function display_data(seldate) {

        $("#scheduleDate").html(seldate);
        var dataString = 'seldate='+ seldate;
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getdata.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#Schedule").html(data);
            } 
        });

    }

    // Now here is the real code for retaining your Date...
    <?php
    if (!empty($_GET['date'])) {
        ?>
    display_data('<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?>')
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    document.getElementById('Date').value = '<?php echo @$_GET["date"]; ?>';

});
```

Now you just need to call the `display_data()` function on a specific date when the dom is ready.

**You can also make use of sessions:**

Example: In my php code store the `$request_date` in a session.

First Start the session if you haven't already started it `session_start()`. In all the pages, The HTML and DELETE PHP and UPDATE FAIL pages.

```
$request_date = $row['date'];
$_SESSION['date'] = $request_date;
```

And also change the redirection part back to your code.

```
header("Location: appoint.php");
```

Now change this part of the Script Block of mine:

From:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['date'])) {
    ?>
    display_data('<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?>');
    <?php
}
?>
document.getElementById('Date').value = '<?php echo @$_GET["date"]; ?>';
```

To:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SESSION['date'])) {
    ?>
    display_data('<?php echo $_SESSION["date"]; ?>');
    <?php
    unset($_SESSION['date']);
}
?>
document.getElementById('Date').value = '<?php echo @$_SESSION["date"]; ?>';
```

The advantage of using session is if you have a delete fail and are redirected to Update Fail page. After that when you come back to the listing page again. You will be right where you left that list.

Comment: I will try in an hour, and will reply to you

Answer (score 0):

with From posting after Ajax call it's not possible to retrieve the data which you first fetch with Ajax method so you need another Ajax method to delete the record from database.

First replace this

```
<form action='/clinic form/appoint/delete.php'=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>' method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Done">
</form>
```

in `getdata.php` with this

```
<button type="button" class="DelMe" data-id="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">Delete Me</button>
```

Then in same `getdata.php` you have `<tr>` add a class to it `<tr class="deleted">` and at end you have `<?php } } ?>` make following changes and put a delete Ajax method call in it so when you fetch the records from database delete Ajax method call will load with the data and will be DOM ready.

```
<?php } ?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".DelMe").on('click', function(){
                var DelId =$(this).data('id');     
                var dataString = 'DelId='+ DelId;
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $(this).parents(".deleted").hide(500);
                    } 
                });
            });
    });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Final `getdata.php` will be like this

```
<?php require_once ('../include/global.php');
    if($_POST['seldate']) {
        $selDate = $_POST['seldate'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM clinic.appoint WHERE date='$selDate'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr class="deleted">
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['time'] ?></td>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['name'] ?></td>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $rows['date'] ?></td>
        <td scope="row"><button type="button" class="DelMe" data-id="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">Delete Me</button></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".DelMe").on('click', function(){
            var DelId =$(this).data('id');       
            var dataString = 'DelId='+ DelId;
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $(this).parents(".deleted").hide(500);
                } 
            });
        });
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Now Create New PHP file and name it `delete.php`

```
<?php require_once ('../include/global.php');
    if($_POST['DelId']) {
        $DelId = $_POST['DelId'];
        $sql="DELETE FROM appoint WHERE id='$DelId'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($rowcount > 0) {
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "false";
        }   
    } 
?>
```

When the row will be deleted, it will be hidden from the user.